# How do i use set identities to simplify an expression for sets A,B, C

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I don't quite understand how I can simplify the following using set identities from a textbook question.....
$$((A\cap C)-(A\cap B\cap C))\cap (B-(A\cap B)-(B\cap C))\cap A'$$

Comment: Do you have to do it using a given list of identities, or can you do it another way? If you need to use a given list of identities, you should share that list with us.

Comment: the specific theorem used in the text book is de morgan's law for sets

Comment: You need to tell us what you have tried so far.